# Numpy failing to properly square array

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, perfect-square

I'm trying to map a simple quadratic function, where zs is a numpy array and R is a constant

```
Ns = -np.square(zs) + 2*zs*R+ 3*R**2
```

It works fine most of the time, but for some reason whenever I have the evaluation set up as following the code breaks:

```
>>>zs = np.array(range(80262,80268)
>>>R = 26756
>>>Ns = -np.square(zs) + 2*zs*R+ 3*R**2
>>>print Ns
array([    642108,    535095,    428080,    321063,    214044
       4295074319], dtype=int64)
```

That last value in the array should be 107023. Whenever I go above 80267, the squaring function breaks completely and starts giving me absolutely ridiculous answers. Is this just a data type error, or is something else going on here that I don't know about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble is that `zs = np.array(range(80262,80268))` creates an array of `int32` values.

`np.square(zs)` returns an array of the same datatype as `zs` and the final squared value in the array overflows the four bytes of memory it's been allocated.

You see that `Ns = -np.square(zs) + 2*zs*R+ 3*R**2` has a datatype of `int64` because NumPy has given this array more memory in order to accommodate the larger numbers. However, it's too late: you already have an overflowed value in `np.square(zs)`.

To solve the issue, create `zs` using the `np.int64` datatype:

```
zs = np.arange(80262, 80268, dtype=np.int64)
```

Be aware that the same problem will occur again if the numbers in `zs` get large enough!